# How can I identify a distribution?

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics

I have data that looks like this when I plot a histogram. I have this data for several years (this is a count of values per group) and each year looks very similar.

[image: example distribution]

Is there a way that I can:

1. more accurately describe this distribution (with words or with a function)
2. compare a distribution from the current year to previous ones? I'm a bit unsure what approaches are used when considering distributions but I'd like to change a process so that it looks less like the image on the left and more like the image on the right

[image]

Comment: You have the data, right?

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you want to do? *Describing*, *estimating* and *comparing* distributions are three very different things.

Comment: I'd say histograms are a perfectly valid approach

Comment: It's usually not necessary to identify a specific distributional model, but even if it were, I wouldn't just start with a histogram. Indeed  if you're using the same data as you want to perform inference on, that will carry some problems with it.

Comment: I do have the data - what I'd like to do is first have a way of describing the distribution. Something like `long-tail` or `normal distribution` (I don't think it's normal, nor am I sure of appropriate distribution terms.) I would then like to have some way of comparing the current year to other years (perhaps this is a different question though)

Comment: I would check this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions. The is the domain $[0,\infty)$, then something like Gamma or exponential distribution may be a good start. Note also that nothing is stopping you from transforming variables to create new distributions

Comment: I usually use the definition of the variable (the thing being measured) to give context to any attempt at description. Descriptively it's right skew with what looks like a clear lower bound. The fact that it also appears to be cut off on the right is curious. Can you explain more about why that might be?